# "from _json import..." - python

Tags: python, json, import, module

I am inspecting the JSON module of python 3.1, and am currently in /Lib/json/scanner.py. At the top of the file is the following line:

```
from _json import make_scanner as c_make_scanner
```

There are five .py files in the module's directory: `__init__` (two leading and trailing underscores, it's formatting as bold), decoder, encoder, scanner and tool. There is no file called "json".

My question is: when doing the import, where exactly is "make_scanner" coming from?

Yes, I am very new to Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be coming from a file, or it may be built-in. On Windows, it appears to be built-in.

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 21 2010, 00:41:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _json
>>> _json.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

and there is no `_json.pyd` or `_json.dll` in the offing.

If you want to see the **source**, having a binary file on your machine or not is irrelevant -- you'll need the [SVN browser](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/_json.c?view=markup).

Comment: I am receiving the same "'module' object has no attribute '__file__'" message. Does this mean that there is no way to see make_scanner?

Answer (score 6):

It's coming from a C-compiled `_json.pyd` (or `_json.so`, etc, etc, depending on the platform) that lives elsewhere on the `sys.path`.  You can always find out where that is in your specific Python installation by importing the module yourself and looking at its `__file__`, e.g.:

```
>>> import _json
>>> _json.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_json.so'
```

As you see, in my installation of Python 2.6, `_json` comes from the `lib-dynload` subdirectory of `lib/python2.6`, and the extension used on this platform is `.so`.